# Subtracting matrices of the same dimension, how to make them align?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, align, matrices, size

This question has been burning inside of my soul for a while now

Sometimes I would like to subtract two matrices of the exact same dimension, but since they differ in content ever so slightly, therefore the size that comes out are not the same.

**For example**: This line of code generates

```
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} x_1^2 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2^2 \end{bmatrix}
```

[image]

As you can see the second matrix is slightly larger. Is there some way to either make the first matrix larger, or align the two matrices at the top?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Macro `\vphantom` can be used to insert invisible vertical space with the height and depth of the argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \vphantom{x_1^2}x_1 & 0 \\
    0 & x_2\vphantom{x_2^2}
  \end{bmatrix}
   - \begin{bmatrix} x_1^2 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2^2 \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Who would have thought of using a macro with phantom in its name

Comment: @BeachedWhale - Don Knuth, the creator of TeX, came up with the name. :-) In fact, there's `\phantom` and `\hphantom` as well as `\vphantom`. The "h" and "v" stand for horizontal and vertical, respectively. `\phantom{A}` is an invisible object -- hence, a "phantom" -- with the exact height, depth, and width of its argument, here, the letter "A".

Answer (score 6):

Instead of inserting custom-sized `\vphantom`s, you could also insert `\mathstrut` directives -- one each in both rows of the first `bmatrix`. (Aside: `\mathstrut` is defined as `\vphantom{(}`, i.e., a `\mathstrut` is a vertical phantom with the depth and height of a `(` parenthesis.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "bmatrix" environment
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{bmatrix} 
  x_1\mathstrut & 0 \\ 
  0\mathstrut & x_2 
  \end{bmatrix}
  -
  \begin{bmatrix} 
  x_1^2 & 0 \\ 
  0 & x_2^2 
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `\bracketMatrixstack` of the `tabstackengine` package is automatically `\strut`ted, and so both matrices are of the same height.  Note that inter-column gap and inter-row baselineskip can also be set independently, by way of

```
\setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.3\normalbaselineskip}
```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.3\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{document}
\[
  \bracketMatrixstack{x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2}
- \bracketMatrixstack{ x_1^2 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2^2 }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can modify (locally) `\arraystretch`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
My solution is to act on \verb|\arraystretch|
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1 & 0 \\
  0 & x_2
\end{bmatrix} - 
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1^2 & 0 \\
  0 & x_2^2
\end{bmatrix}
\]
and it can be compared with Heiko's using \verb|\vphantom|
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  \vphantom{x_1^2}x_1 & 0 \\
  0 & x_2\vphantom{x_2^2}
\end{bmatrix} -
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_1^2 & 0 \\
  0 & x_2^2
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Resetting `\arraystretch` should be done *outside* alignment environments such as `align`, because alignment cells form groups. It's not difficult to define a new environment taking as argument the factor `\arraystretch` should be reset to.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a construction a bit complicated with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix` but which ensures a perfect alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{[cc]c[cc]}
x_1 & 0 & \Block{2-1}{-} & x_1^2 & 0 \\
0   & x_2 & & 0 & x_2^2 \\
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]